# How to pass along dynamic amount in PaymentIntent

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I have hardcoded a price into my Next.js using Stripe test project but would like the amount paid to change upon submission from an input. I am specifically wondering how I pass along that data in the paymentIntent function I wrote:

```
//In Checkout.js

try {
        const {
                error,
                paymentIntent: { status },
                
              } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(paymentIntent.client_secret, {
                payment_method: {
                  card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
                 amount: myAmountVariable //trying to pass
                },
              });


//In payment.js:

  paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount,
    currency: "usd"
  });


  return {
    props: {
      paymentIntent,
    },
  };
};

const CheckoutPage = ({ paymentIntent }) => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <CheckoutForm paymentIntent={paymentIntent} />
  </Elements>
);
```

The above code, where I am attempting to pass in 'amount' gives me the error "Amount is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit an amount in `confirmCardPayment` -- that's not supported. If you want to adjust the amount, you need to have your client application send that `amount` to your server to [update the payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-amount) prior to confirming it with `confirmCardPayment` in Stripe.js.

On the server:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
  'pi_1234',
  {amount: myAmountVariable}
);
```

I want to make sure that you're not including `stripe-node` in your client application, and that your secret is only only being used server side (eg, to create the payment intent). This is critical for security.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My question more has to do with the correct away to pass along 'myAmountVariable'? For example, can you demonstrate how it would be passed from the controller where its inputted (Checkout.js) and then received  on the payment.js page?

Comment: I'd say you'd pass `amount` as a json body parameter when you fetch the payment intent client secret from your back end. 1/ User fills out elements form + amount, click button 2/ you send amount with create PI request to server 3/ create PI with custom amount and send back client secret 4/ Call confirmCardPayment with client secret.